# AWS MSK - Kafka Brokers added to AWS public DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, dns, terraform, aws-msk

We are using this Terraform module to provision Kafka on AWS:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/msk_cluster

The brokers are registered on AWS Public DNS, is it possible to prevent this and register the brokers on a hosted zone within the VPC instead?

Comment: I don't use MSK, but seems like you're asking about the client_subnets config property which should be setting up the advertised listeners

Comment: We are setting private subnets there.  Having checked the TF module and the AWS docs it doesn't seem there is any way to prevent the brokers from being advertised publicly.  I feel like I'm missing something because this just seems odd.

Comment: Has MSK support given any advice?